# Does Picasso library (Android version) save photos after app is closed or device is rebooted?

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

Using Picasso library to load images in an Android app. Does Picasso save the images to reload them in the app after the app gets closed or device gets rebooted?

Comment: mmm why don't prove by yourself? so lazy? If' you don't have time to make your own examples.. we don't have time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

the last version i used did not. They should be cached when they are downloaded and attached to the view you are using. ie ImageView. I would check documentation

http://square.github.io/picasso/